# match the number from comma separated value and count

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a comma separated value in A2 and same numbers in different cells B1, C1, D1.... I want to match them from comma separated value and find out the count in B2, C2, D2. Please see the image attached you will get the context.

[image]

Can we achieve this by formula or macro in excel?

Tried formula:

```
=LEN(TRIM($A$2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($A$2),C1,","""))
```

Also, I have two data sets where I will be using this formula to find out the count of number from comma-separated value and based on count I want the repeated ones to come in a different cell please refer the image for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: image? and where is the code you have tried?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7tsd.png

Comment: i tried to do it with excel formula but unable to achieve the desired result.  =LEN(TRIM($A$2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($A$2),C1,","""))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but get the job done. Please note it is case-sensitive and please make sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing this formula.

```
{=SUM(--(EXACT("!"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,",",REPT(" ",100)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2)))-1)*100+1,100)),"!"&B1)))}
```

You can replace `!` in the above formula with a unique symbol that will never appear in the text string to be safer.

The logic is to **SUBSTITUTE** the comma `,` with and long string of blanks, then use **MID** to find each value in the text string and return the result as an array, then use **EXACT** to match each value in the array with the look up value and return a new array of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, then **SUM** up all `TRUE` which will give the count of the look up value.

[image: Solution3]

> **UPDATE #2**

As requested by OP, here is one way of solving the second query which is to match the same value with the same occurrence from two text strings separated by comma `,`.

[image: Update2]

The formula in Cell `C2` is from the original solution which is used to find the occurrence of a given value in a text string;

The formula for Range `C6:K6` is an **array formula** as shown below. I used a helper row to layout the matching values, **and excluding the one that has `0` count for both data set**;

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$K$1,,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS($C$1:$K$1)))/($C$2:$K$2=$C$3:$K$3)/($C$2:$K$2>0),COLUMN()-2))&",","")}
```

The formula in Cell `L8` is concatenating all values from Range `C6:K6` and remove the last comma `,` from the final text string:

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6),LEN(CONCATENATE(C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6))-1)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help Terry W, I have tried solution 1 it is working right with single-digit values but in decimals, it is counting 1.2 and 11.2 as same pls refer the image for more https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EhHw.png

Comment: Just tried Solution 2 all count values are coming as 0 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLVQC.png

Comment: Works like a charm the only issue is the formula is not counting 8.10, 9.10

Comment: Great... it is working... I have another query I need to compare two data sets and extract those which are same pls refer the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/zktpE.png

Comment: Hi Terry, I have added my additional query to my original post. Also, this is the final step of my query which I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Terry W, Thanks for your support, I have tried the solution provided by you step by step but I am getting a different result here pls refer the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RJ4P.png

Comment: @SameerFarooqui thanks again for the debugging. I have amended the second formula for range `C6:K6` in my updated screen-shot to take out the value that has `0` count for both data set. It should be working just fine now.

Comment: Hi Terry W, You are a lifesaver it worked appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Terry, I have asked a different question regarding filter data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809427/countif-1-and-1-in-filter/57809467#57809467 Please check if you can help.

Comment: Hi Terry, I tried to implement the formula in my template, there is a very strange error coming up. There are 33 numbers in comma-separated cell and when I am applying the formula to find out the occurrences it is missing one number due to which the total count is not coming correct. For ref I am sharing the example file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ncHMqZpUUbwf_g4eSACsKNBHp3rUDLp_

Comment: @SameerFarooqui the issue was caused by insufficient blanks between `9.3` and `9.4` when using **MID** to extract the value using  every 100 characters interval. Replace all `100` with `1000` in my original formula should solve the issue unless you need to deal with text string that is longer than 1000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me, give it a try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=(LEN(","&SUBSTITUTE($A$2,",",",,")&",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(","&SUBSTITUTE($A$2,",",",,")&",",","&B$1&",","")))/LEN(","&B$1&",")
```

Drag right...

Comment: I just tested but putting `,` in front of B1 will not give the correct answer for value `10`. I think just putting `,` at the end of B1 is sufficient? Also you may want to trim A2 just in case there is space at the end of the test string?

Comment: @TerryW, you are correct, I edited :). About your suggestion: It's exactly what I had at first (if you look at the editions) however that would fail too when you would go use `11` etc. I think all scenarios are covered now.

Comment: your edited formula will return `0` for value `11` in this string `a1,A1,2,3cd,3c,d4,5,6,07e,8,8,9,10,10,a1,11   ` which has a few blank spaces at the end of the string. That's why I suggest to trim the string.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing it is to simply calculate the difference in the length of the string minus the length of the string when replacing the value searched by nothing and dividing by the length of the string searched
The formula would be:

```
=(LEN($A$1)+1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1&",",B1&",","")))/LEN(B1&",")
```

[image]

Comment: Try this text string `1,1.10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,10,11       ` (with a few blank space at the end of the string) and your formula will not find the correct count for value `11` and `10`. If you **TRIM** the text string, the formula will not return the correct count for value `1` and `10`. Not to mention if there is alphanumerical value in the text string such as `a1`, `A1` etc. The count for value `1` will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution:

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT($A$2, ","), B1)
```

[image]

Comment: getting the function is invalid. You must be using some macro to split the values.

Comment: This is `Google Sheets` and the function is not available in `Excel`.