# Countif 1 and -1 in filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count 1 and -1 in filtered data. The count for -1 is correct but for 1 it includes -1 as well and shows the count which is incorrect. If you look at the image attached the count for "1" should be one instead it is showing 3 which means it is counting -1 as well. For more info refer the image

[image]

formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B11,ROW(B2:B11)-MIN(ROW(B2:B11)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",B2:B11))+0)
```

formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B11,ROW(B2:B11)-MIN(ROW(B2:B11)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-1",B2:B11))+0)
```

Comment: This article has the [solution](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria) with detailed explanation. I think the problem of your formula is the use of **SEARCH**. JvdV has already helped you out. I came up a slightly different formula which also dose the job I believe. To count **1**, try this `{=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B11)-MIN(ROW(B2:B11)),,))*(IF(ISNUMBER(--B2:B11),B2:B11,0)=1))}`; To count **-1**, try this `{=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B11)-MIN(ROW(B2:B11)),,))*(IF(ISNUMBER(--B2:B11),B2:B11,0)=-1))}`. Both are **array formula**.

Comment: Next time when you have a question, make sure to mention all possible scenarios such as has error value in the range, some value looks like number but is actually text, etc. So other contributors can provide a more spot on answer without coming back and forth in the comments. It is a good questions and I have given you an up-vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small example:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B7,ROW(B2:B7)-ROW(B2),0,1)),--(B2:B7=1))
```

Formula in `F1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B7,ROW(B2:B7)-ROW(B2),0,1)),--(B2:B7=-1))
```

---

***Result***

[image]

[image]

---

If you can't use the above because of error values as per your comment, one thing you could do is to build an array of values with some `IF` statements like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B7,ROW(B2:B7)-ROW(B2),0,1)),IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B7),IF(B2:B7=1,1),0))
```

and:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B7,ROW(B2:B7)-ROW(B2),0,1)),IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B7),IF(B2:B7=-1,1),0))
```

Both formula entered as arrayformula!

Comment: It is working as you described but the only problem is if there is an error in between #VALUE it is stopping the formula to execute. Please check if there is any workaround to this.

Comment: I can but the values in the filter are dependant on other cells which I can't control. It would be great if there is any way to filter out the #VALUE in the formula itself.

Comment: Thanks, JvdV, worked like a charm appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(102,OFFSET(B2:B11,ROW(B2:B11)-MIN(ROW(B2:B11)),,1))*(B2:B11=1))` to find count of 1's

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(102,OFFSET(B2:B11,ROW(B2:B11)-MIN(ROW(B2:B11)),,1))*(B2:B11=-1))`  to find count of -1's

Just lock the cells as necessary and you're good to go.

Comment: but I want this to work with filter data. If I apply the filter it will not adjust the count