# Need help calculating the amount of times an ID is repeated in a column BY MONTH

Tags: excel-formula

I'm having some trouble finishing up this formula. I need to calculate the amount of customers that have 2+ requests (I can do that by counting how many times the customer ID repeats itself in the query results). The problem is that I can't filter the results by month.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/oLVGf0Y.png]

formula I'm currently using: =IF(COUNTIF($C$3:$C$10;C3)>1;1/COUNTIF($C$3:$C$10;C3);0)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer as the solution. I just realised that once added the helper column to show the visibility of the filtered rows, you can simply use **COUNTIFS** in your original formula column to return the sum... I have overthinking the case... Anyway I have updated my solution with the formula approach hope it also helps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a table with one column showing customer ID per request and another column showing the month number of the month from which the request was made.

You want to be able to **filter** this table and return the **total count** of customers that have made more than one request based on the **filtered** result.

In your post you mentioned you are not getting the correct count when you filtered the `month` but in your screen-shot it seems that you are not getting the correct count when you filtered the `ID`.

Regardless, you are not getting the correct count from a **filtered table** based on your current formula.

**There are solutions here to deal with [finding count from a filtered table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809427/countif-1-and-1-in-filter/57809467#57809467)**, but in your case you are not simply counting the `ID`, but counting the `ID` that appeared more than once, and the appearances may vary if you filter the `month`.

If you are only filtering the `ID`, the answer to the above question I linked should also answer yours. If you want a solution that is working for filtering either `ID`, `month` or both, you will need a **helper column** to detect the visibility of the filtered rows and then use **COUNTIFS** instead of **COUNTIF** in your original formula to take into account the helper column.

[image: 01]

As shown above, I have added a helper column called **Visibility** to find out whether a row is filtered or not. The formula is:

```
=AGGREGATE(3,5,C3)>0
```

It will return `TURE` for all visible rows and `FALSE` for the hidden ones (although it is not visible from the filtered table). In the above example I have filtered out `2` in the `ID` column.

Once the helper column is added, you can rewrite your original formula as below:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$10;C3;Helper_Column;TRUE)>1;1/COUNTIF($C$3:$C$10;C3;Helper_Column;TRUE);0)
```

> **POWER QUERY** Approach

Here is how I did it in **`#powerquery`** for those who might be interested...

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

This approach also requires the use of the **helper column** to show the visibility of filtered rows. Then use the **From Table** function under the `Data` tab to add the source table to **Power Query Editor**, then you should have:

[image: 02]

You can see from the screen-shot that the visibility for ID `2` is `FALSE`.

Next, filter out all `FALSE` in the Visibility column, then you should have something similar to the filtered source table:

[image: 03]

Next, use the **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab to count the number of appearance per ID.

[image: 04]

Next, filter the Count that is `>1` and you should have the following:

[image: 05]

Next, use the **Count Values** under **Statistics** function under the `Transform` tab to count the number of `ID`, and you should have `2` returned as shown below:

[image: 06]

Lastly, **Close & Load** the result to a new worksheet (by default) or to the current worksheet with the source table (need to amend your query setting) as shown below:

[image: 07]

If I change the filter in the source table to show all `ID` but exclude `2` in the `month`, I just need to right click the output table and select **Refresh** to get an updated result.

[image: 08]

Need to give credit to the following two articles which hinted the use of the Visibility column in Power Query:

[Using Excel Slicers To Pass Parameters To Power Query Queries](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/03/09/using-excel-slicers-to-pass-parameters-to-power-query-queries/)

[Use a 'Visible' Column in Formulas to Ignore Hidden Rows in Filtered Tables](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/visible-column-in-excel-tables.htm)

Here are the Power Query M codes behind the scene for reference only. All steps are performed using built-in functions without advanced coding.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"month", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Visibility] = true),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows1", {"ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Count] > 1),
    #"Calculated Count" = List.NonNullCount(#"Filtered Rows"[ID])
in
    #"Calculated Count"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Switch to COUNTIFS and add the months:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$10,C3,$D$3:$D$10,D3)>1,1/COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$10,C3,$D$3:$D$10,D3),0)
```

[image]

---

Just an FYI this can be done without the need of the helper column:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$10,$C$3:$C$10,$D$3:$D$10,$D$3:$D$10)>1,1/COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$10,$C$3:$C$10,$D$3:$D$10,$D$3:$D$10),0))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]